# Create SQL Server Login using VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am new here and I am learning how to use `vb.net` and `sql server`.  I have experimented creating a login in `Sql server` using `SSMS`. But i'm wondering is it possible to create a login using `vb.net` application?

**Update**

I tried the query generated from `SSMS`.

```vb
qry = "CREATE LOGIN test WITH PASSWORD = 123"
```

Then i used this connection

```vb
Dim con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=server;Initial Catalog= master;trusted_connection = yes")
```

but when i run it using `ExecuteNonQuery` it says *incorrect syntax near '123'*.So I run the same `TSQL` in `SSMS` and it works fine.

Comment: Instead of wondering, just give it a try. Once you've given it a go, and you have an actual problem, give us a shout. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to help you understand what a good question looks like.

Comment: With most of the actions you perform in SSMS, you'll find a script changes button window at the top - you can run SQL script from VB.NET, so combine the two!

Comment: Please, refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx#Anchor_3) MSDN article. You can run this query's from vb.net.

Comment: I've realized my mistake the password should be enclosed in quotation marks. Sorry for the trouble :)